# What can you do when the question you want to ask is a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Someone has a question that they want to ask; but the question (or one that is *very* similar) has been asked already (and possibly long abandoned). There may be minor changes between the asker's situation and the originally asked question, but the general question is practically identical. The question already has one or more answers - none of which are accepted - and none of which worked for (or can be used by) the asker.

**What is the recommended course of action for the asker?**

Create the duplicate - while linking to the original and explaining it didn't work?

Add a comment to the original in the hopes of drawing attention to it? (What if the asker is a new user and doesn't have comment-anywhere permission? - This wouldn't this even bump the question...)

Place a bounty? (Again, what if the user is too new to do so?)

Something else I can't think of?

Comment: This is a good question. The problem is that there are things one can do if it's their own question (like edit, provide a new / better SSCCE, accept an answer) that they can't on someone else's dup. But why should the new asker be penalized if they want to put the work into an abandoned unanswered dup?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If the post has answers that are valid for that question, but that don't work for you, then the post *isn't* a duplicate.  As a new question, include a link to the related question, and explain how it differs from your situation and/or why the existing answer to that question are not working for you.

If the answers to that question don't actually solve *that* question, in addition to not answering *your* question, then for all intents and purposes the question is unanswered, and you're simply asking [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions).

Comment: The question you linked to doesn't address the ideal course of action if the question is someone else's old, unanswered question.

Comment: @Alexander That's *exactly* what the question addresses.  It lists a number of options you have available to you.  You're welcome to perform as many of them as you would like.  There is no single "best" option among them, in the general case.

Comment: The answer says "edit your question" - do you recommend simply taking it over - possibly entering specifics that may not have been applicable to his situation(?), or post a bounty - which in many cases isn't ideal. For example: rep that is too low to post one (<75), or low enough that it's at best a gamble. The last comment to the answer (by GreenAsJade) nails my feelings on that part.

Comment: @Alexander You're free to edit the question to improve it in any ways that editing any other user's questions are allowed, namely improving the presentation of the content without changing the content itself.  If the actual content of the posts are different, then they aren't duplicates, because you are in a slightly different situation.  You should not be adding details in an edit, you should be improving the readability of the existing details.  As for the bounties, if you don't have enough reputation to post a bounty, then cross that option off of the list.  It changes nothing else.

Comment: @Servy if you have enough rep, should you take ownership of the duplicate question as if it were your own (since you can basically do everything except accept an answer) and place a bounty?

Comment: @durron597 In what way did I ever say that?

Comment: @Servy you didn't, I was asking a different question. The answer could easily be "no" :-P

Comment: If you're asking, then no, you should not pretend that the question is your own.  However there are ways of improving or drawing attention to a post that is not your own, most notably editing, comments (to a point), and bounties.

Comment: @Servy - This extension is a bit more of a hypothetical, but perhaps you would have some insight: If you start off with the assumption that your question is essentially the same and start trying to draw attention to it (especially if you were to place a bounty on it) - but those who come to the question help you realize that you need more details than were contained in the original question - what would you recommend doing there? Abandon the question to create your own? (Abandon the bounty as well, letting the auto-award run its course?)

Comment: @Alexander If the existing question does not have enough information to be answerable then it should be closed accordingly, and you would differentiate your question from it by including enough information for it to be answered.  If someone else has posted a question without enough information for it to be answered, and you can create one that *is* answerable, then they aren't duplicates.

Comment: @Servy the "number of options" the answer lists seems to be 2. And one of them doesn't apply if the question is not yours to begin with. Is there a way you could make it more useful in this instance?

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier You can still edit a question to improve it even if it is not your question.  You're somewhat more limited in the types of edits that you can make; you can't be adding entirely new information, but that doesn't mean you can't improve it at all.

Comment: this seems a bit elusive... two questions may ask the exact same thing. but we've all seen it: question A ask X for Y and question B ask X for Z, they may both have an accepted answer, they may be totally different, they're technically a duplicate in terms of X but in reality neither actually address X. one shall rewrite both questions so they ask A:X-for-Y and B:X-for-Z, I guess.

Comment: @naxa If it's not a part of the question that they're asking about doing X for something else, then what the reader does with X is *irrelevant*.  If the question is actually phrased as asking for Z or Y, but that wonders if solving X might accomplish it, then the questions indeed aren't duplicates as they're asking about Y and Z.

Comment: This may differ for other sites of the network right? Because on arqade .se there are sometimes people complaining about bug. the answer is "Today a patch fixed this bug" And after posting the same problem again 3 weeks later (so obvisiously with the fixing patch added) they said it is a duplicate anyway and I should jsut add a bount to the question if I'm looking for an additional answer, and the existing answers aren't helping.

Comment: @Zaibis This is the Stack Overflow meta.  If you want to discuss Arqade then you should do so on their meta.

Answer (score 14):

If you are going to reheat old topics by posting a new question, **make abundantly clear *why* the existing solutions do not apply to your case.** Then it's not a duplicate. E.g.:

> **Fooing the bar, when X**
>
> I'm trying to foo the bar using baz, but I get error XYZ.
>
> [sample code] [clear error message]
>
> In researching this I have come across these solutions [link here], but they do not work for me because:
>
> 1. Solution A doesn't apply because X.
> 2. Solution B doesn't work because it produces a different error FGH.

A question posed this way is clearly a new and very answerable question. Unless you make these clear distinctions, it would easily qualify as a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, this seems like a good approach. I would add to that that a person might need to add links to the posts at the very beginning, as if a question gets marked as a duplicate at some point, then it might need some effort to unmark it, as people might review it automatically as a duplicate, once it was already marked as such in the past.

Comment: Well, you will want to write a clear, readable, understandable question. You will want to *communicate effectively* in writing. That doesn't mean putting links first. That doesn't mean writing defensively from the beginning. It means that you need to set the expectations of the reader correctly. You can simply hint at the fact that this topic is very similar to another one in a single sentence, perhaps even in the title, as shown in my example ("..., when X"). You can then go into more detail about the differentiation later on and still pose a clear problem statement first.

Answer (score 3):

I think so. That's what bounties are for. If you believe once asked question didn't get enough attention, put a bounty for it and explain your reasoning.

Comment: Hm, but I can't add a bounty to a question that it isn't my-own :/

Comment: @Aleks Who says so? You can. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: Heh, I have rechecked the claim, and now I see I clicked on a question that wasn't even alienable for bounty still. My mistake. But nevertheless, not everyone has enough credits to add bounty on every question that might not have adequate answers for their problem.