# Is it okay to intentionally duplicate a question if you think you can ask it better?

Tags: discussion

This question is similar, but not quite exactly the same as [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253924/what-to-do-when-the-question-you-want-to-ask-is-a-duplicate) one.

If the question I want to ask has already been asked **and satisfactorily answered**, but the way the question could have been asked better. I want to ask it more clearly, in the hopes that I might increase search traffic and make it easier for others to understand. Should I post the question, perhaps with a link to the old one?

Comment: Can you edit the existing question in a way that improves how it is worded without changing the meaning or any code?

Comment: @murgatroid99 No. In this (hypothetical) case the edit would involve a complete overhaul of the question, and I don't think it's appropriate to edit a question that way.

Comment: Would the edit change the meaning of the question? Would the edit change the code in the question? If the answer to both of those is no, an edit is probably fine, and given your rep, others would review it. If the answer to either of those questions is yes, in what sense is it the same question?

Comment: @murgatroid99 for example, the question might have been asked originally with code that was hard to read, or overly specific. I could ask a question with exactly the same meaning, but different (perhaps more general) code that would be easier for future readers to understand.

Comment: Yes and no. Your question needs to be sufficiently different that it doesn't get outright deleted. You should endeavour to self answer as well, so when your question gets closed as a duplicate it will not get pruned by the system after a set period of time. If the original question was bad enough then you should take a crack at writing a canonical version of it.

Comment: The key thing is: does your duplicate add value? Is it sufficient value to keep your duplicate? How many future users will your duplicate help?