# Is it wrong to use an upvote to balance out a downvote?

Tags: discussion, voting, upvotes, zero-voted-posts

I know I can upvote any post for any reason, but consider this situation:

I see a zero score post, and I don't think it needs either an upvote or downvote. Suddenly it gets a downvote, but I think the post should not have been downvoted, so I upvote the post.

If I upvote the post, not because of the context of the post, but because I think the post does not deserve a negative score, is this upvote improper?

Comment: I just up-voted to get this one back to zero, but typically I try to vote without regard for the current net total.

Comment: Well, what part of a post makes you feel like "it should not have a negative score"? Isn't that in itself akin to wanting to show your approval?

Comment: You should upvote useful content, downvote useless content and not vote on content you don't care either way about. Voting on a post solely because of it's net score is not useful voting information.

Comment: I don't agree with the premise but thanks a lot for bringing the issue up.

Comment: *originally it neither needs to up vote or down vote* - I don't understand what this means.

Comment: @BSMP It means the OP is determining what an appropriate score for the post is, and then votes to bring it closer to that score. The OP feels that zero is an appropriate score, so if the post has received no votes yet, it needs neither an upvote nor a downvote. As soon as it has been downvoted, the OP would upvote it to bring it back to zero. (And presumably, if it had been upvoted, the OP would downvote it to bring it back to zero too.)

Comment: I can't find the meta post I'm looking for, but this came up a few months ago and every upvote you hand out grants the user in question more and more privileges.  Do you want users who post crap content to be able to vote to close questions or even delete content?

Comment: @cimmanon i don't think that applies, in this case the voter presumably doesn't think the post is crap (hence thinking it doesn't deserve to be downvoted)

Comment: Seems that a way to vote against the down voting system, is to up vote any down votes regardless of question content

Comment: Upvote if good; downvote if bad. Ignore current score.

Comment: Related: Sometimes I don't upvote a post, because I think it deserves a few upvotes but not as many as it already has.

Comment: Maybe when someone intends to vote, the current score should not be displayed. To see the score, one would have to say +1, 0 or -1 and that's that. In other words: you can't see the score until you commit yourself. Or, we could just be responsible, rational adults. Ha!

Comment: Downvote should be given with proper reason in comments section. I see people downvoting for no reason. Even post(Question/Answer) was useful. Sometimes people just don't think, they downvote because they just didn't had enough caffeine in morning!!

Comment: @KerrekSB +1 on your comment. That's exactly how I see it too.

Comment: [I don't always downvote, but when I do, I never feel the need to explain why!](http://i.imgur.com/hZVsPlx.jpg)

Comment: [I don't always use memes to express my feelings; but when I do, I always use overused memes](http://i.imgur.com/eidHhBG.jpg) @Jarrod

Comment: If a question was down voted, but the question content is on topic, relevant, shows research, well formulated... the real question is: would I vote it up anyway?

Comment: @TinyGiant - you clicked on it and commented on it so it was effective! ;-)

Comment: *If I upvote the post, not because of the context of the post, but because I think the post does not deserve a negative score, is this upvote improper?* So you vote based on pavlovian responses?

Comment: Well, I downvoted this question because I don't think it deserved all the upvotes. The guy who downvoted, did it because of whatever reasons he had in mind, if I upvote I do it for whatever reason I have in mind. You have one vote, you should do whatever you want with it.

Comment: This is an important question to ask. And it looks like it has been asked many times. I think the main problem with these sites in the lack of accountability in down votes. I'll see valid answers sitting at -5 with no explanation, no comments at all and wonder how not one person who thought the answer was wrong felt it was wrong enough to leave a comment.

Answer (score 289, accepted):

Yeah, that is kind of a problem: you're no longer voting on the post, you're voting on the *score*. Essentially, you're telling someone else they can't vote, rather than accepting that they're entitled to their opinion (and perhaps forming one of your own).

Meanwhile, the author of the post earns +8 in reputation instead of the -2 they'd have gotten if you hadn't voted. Even though you don't have an opinion on *the post* at all. And the downvoter perhaps gets discouraged and stops downvoting, thus increasing the already-pervasive problem of bad content not being adequately indicated.

Please, **vote based on the value of the *post*.** If you don't have an opinion on the value of a given post, *then don't vote.*

### See also:

- [Is voting to balance in the spirit of the site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74666/is-voting-to-balance-in-the-spirit-of-the-site)
- [Upvoting for reasons other than "showing research and effort"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308352/upvoting-for-reasons-other-than-showing-research-and-effort)
- [Do users upvote out of sympathy, and how should that be addressed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254129/do-users-upvote-out-of-sympathy-and-how-should-that-be-addressed)
- [Should sympathy votes be used to counter unexplained downvotes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134613/should-sympathy-votes-be-used-to-counter-unexplained-downvotes)
- [Is there an actual "pity" or "sympathy" upvote problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93356/is-there-an-actual-pity-or-sympathy-upvote-problem)

Comment: speaking from my experience as a downvoter, "perhaps gets discouraged" - yes. "...and stops downvoting" - no

Comment: If there is one thing on the site that might discourage, it is pity upvotes. I mean how the heck do you reason with people who rage against the machine when you do that on behalf of the machine?

Comment: If you don't think the post should be negative, you clearly do have an opinion on the post, and you are therefore allowed to vote on it.

Comment: I must be of a rare opinion, that downvoting a weak potentially useful is bad enough to warrant an upvote to put it back to zero. At least I feel the need to do it rarely.

Comment: @Blorgbeard If you wouldn't have upvoted it if it hadn't been downvoted, but you are upvoting it if it has been downvoted, then clearly, you *don't* vote based on your opinion of the post. Your opinion of the post may already be a factor in your voting behaviour, but it should be the *only* factor in your voting behaviour.

Comment: I'm usually the first to advocate being welcoming to newcomers and less experienced members, but I only believe an upvote is warrented if the question is actually worthy of an upvote by itself. I don't personally tend to downvote first posts with minor issues, but if it was technically warranted by some measure, I just won't vote at all. Instead, I'll usually comment to explain how the question/answer could be improved. In short, I agree - **vote on the question/answer's own merit, not to cancel out someone else's vote in either direction**.

Comment: And I'd also agree that a sympathy upvote harms everyone involved, because it gives a net gain. Even if the "score" is 0, the rep gain is positive, and that is what the user will watch. Given a positive rep score, they're more likely to post similar bad content because "someone thought it was right." If you don't feel it is worthy of a downvote, but not worthy by itsef of an upvote, don't vote.

Comment: @JasonMc92 so you're saying that the effect on the user's rep is a factor in your voting decisions?

Comment: @Blorgbeard, not a major one, but if it has a few minor problems and they're new, I don't personally downvote...I prefer to provide helpful comments and give them a chance to improve. Major problems, you bet I'll downvote. It's a personal policy, and I understand different people have different opinions (so long as a downvote is based on merit, or lack thereof, and not *exclusively* to be nasty, I can agree to disagree.) This issue of anti-voting exists in both directions, really, and it's a problem either way.

Comment: When I vote on an answer, I'm not just saying "this answer is good" or "this answer is bad". I'm saying "the reader would benefit from seeing this answer *earlier*" or "*later*". If I see an answer with score -1 that I think is superior to an answer with score +2, I will vote the former up. If I think the former is *vastly* superior to the latter, I will also vote the latter down to help make sure the superior question is displayed first, which is, IMO, the ultimate goal of this voting practice.

Comment: Exactly. The *purpose* of the voting system is to rate content so that users see the best content first. How users get rep when their content is voted on is *not* my problem. If it's broken, fix it; don't try to train users to vote around it.

Comment: There's a fine line though. Your vote should be because the post was good quality, or bad quality. If you're voting because you don't think it was bad but someone else did, that's the behavior that causes problems. if you thought it was good/high quality, upvote away. Upvoting something that you think is "just ok" because someone else downvoted though isn't ok.

Comment: This answer seems to be responding to an imaginary question that reads "I saw an answer at -1. I didn't read the answer, but I don't like negative numbers, so I upvoted it. Is that ok?". Whereas, actually, the OP did read the answer, and formed an **opinion** on the **content** viz: it belongs at score: 0.

Comment: The question is neither of those, @Blorgbeard. Rather, he states that he feels the post should score 0 and asks if **voting for reasons other than "context"** (sic) is a problem. Which is what I try to address here.

Comment: Voting to *sort* is something else again, @Blorgbeard. A fine distinction, perhaps... But important: if I think Answer A is more useful than Answer B, voting A up is totally appropriate. It doesn't particularly matter if A and B score 0 or -1 or +100 in this context; I'm ranking them according to how useful I found them, not twiddling some meaningless score in a vacuum.

Comment: Re-reading "if I upvote the post, but is not for the context, just think the post should not have a negative score", I actually have no idea what that means.. Assuming context => content, I don't understand how you could believe a post shouldn't be negative without considering its content, unless it *actually is* "I don't like negative numbers", which of course I agree is a Very Bad reason to vote.

Comment: I read it as, it's a post that he feels isn't bad enough to downvote, but isn't good enough to upvote (which means he has evaluated the content.) But, it has a downvote, so he feels the need to upvote it to bring it back to a neutral score, which is misleading because it indicates to others that a user sees the question as good quality, where in reality it's just one user saw it as low quality and the other just saw it as ok quality, not good. *(this is all explained in the linked answers...)*

Comment: Yeah, agree it's not 100% clear, @Blorgbeard - which is why I went back and dug up the related links, since we've covered this topic from a bunch of different angles over the years.

Comment: If I counter-vote in order to bring the score to a value that I think the post deserves, do I not also vote according to the value of the post? I guess even that in the long run both approaches come out the same but counter-voting could maybe converge faster.

Comment: Not only is there a net effect for the answerer, there is a (rather minor) net effect for the down-voter too. They had to spend a point of reputation to downvote. They clearly felt strongly enough to spend that point and a "balancing" vote (if that's all it is) makes that point wasted.

Comment: -1 I think in the OP's question requires that they have considered the overall content quality of a question. Otherwise, they could not say "but I think the post should not have been downvoted." How can you say that and NOT have checked it for quality?

Comment: @joshmcode sure, but upvoting it only because you don't believe it deserves to be downvoted indicates that otherwise you don't believe it should be upvoted either, presumably because the quality isn't that great. By upvoting it you are sending the wrong message (unless you really do feel it is good or better quality, in which case the downvote shouldn't have had any affect anyway)

Comment: to paraphrase Monty Python ***Every downvote is sacred!*** Never waste them, there is a few orders of magnitude more things to downvote than you have downvotes a day!

Comment: If you want voting to be blind we should remove the count. Having the count displayed allows people to gauge relative merit according to users. If I disagree with the relative merit accorded so far I can attempt to re balance it with my votes. E.g. I see an acceptable answer with more votes than a better, perhaps more recent, answer. I may down vote a perfectly good answer to help emphasize a better one. Votes and rep do experience inflation.

Comment: if someone simply votes up on every single post that has a negative score, then I would agree that's "bad" to do. If someone simply thinks that a post is "good enough" to not warrant a down vote, then they are expressing that they think it is a good post. Am I only supposed to upvote if I think something is a "great" post? To me, "useful and clear" doesn't mean "great" -- do I need to say "Wow" audibly before upvoting? I wonder at the utility of distinguishing "good enough", "good", and "great", since each person's vote has a value of +1 or -1 (positive/negative), not +.5 or +.25

Comment: Who are you responding to here, @CodeJockey?

Comment: I suppose you, Shog9, but anyone who wants to read it -- I contend that it's not possible to remove your opinion of the "Context" of the post and still have any concern with what is asked in this question. the only situation where this question becomes valid is if you either randomly or indiscriminately upvote -1 scored posts. If you `think the post should not have been downvoted`, then I would say you think it is at least somewhat good. You are _not_ neutral on it, and therefore justified in voting however you feel (up, in this case). I suppose @KevinB used "great", if he wants to weigh in

Comment: I mean, if you choose to upvote a good post only because it was downvoted, i feel that is the wrong response. If you think it's a good post, upvote it regardless of if it's downvoted. the same in the opposite direction. don't not downvote it just because it's already downvoted, the additional downvotes(and upvotes) do provide a useful signal.

Comment: I'd say that `you're no longer voting on the post, you're voting on the score` is not applicable, because the OP _is_ taking into account their opinion of the post - a positive impression. Users either have a positive, neutral, or negative impression of a post (or perhaps they can't decide (conflict), which _could_ be lumped in anywhere around neutral). If the post is modified, that can help them decide. If they see it downvoted, it can resolve the conflict. In this case, however, they have an opinion on the "context" of the post, it's just clarified by their opposition to another's opinion

Comment: well, no, the OP didn't specify a postive impression in this case, he/she didn't think it needed an upvote, but also didn't think it should have been downvoted. their entire purpose of voting was simply to overthrow someone else's opinion on the question's quality.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're inadvertently making an argument in favor of *not* voting when you feel a post has "enough" votes, @CodeJockey... Which probably isn't something you'd want to encourage.

Comment: Until the mods can figure out how to delete my account (it's still "pending"), I'll have to point out that the downvoting behavior on this site makes me want to puke.  In the meantime, here is a nice recipe for brownies: Directions

    Beat together sugar, eggs, and oil.
    Sift flour, baking powder, salt, and cocoa together.
    Add to sugar-egg mixture.
    Add vanilla and nuts (if desired).
    Pour into two cake pans (8x8x2) lined with foil.
    Bake at 350 degrees for 35 to 40 minutes.
    Cut when cool and dust with powdered sugar.

Comment: Of course, feel free to omit the powdered sugar.

Comment: Thanks for the recipe; your account should be gone now.

Comment: I completely agree that "you're no longer voting on the post, you're voting on the score." but that's exactly why I feel you should cancel out down votes with up votes. I have elaborated in an answer of my own.

Answer (score 10):

### There are three classifications of questions:

1. Questions that deserve to be **downvoted** to oblivion for the reason under the downvote arrow **This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful** these should also automatically merit an appropriate close vote that matches the reason.
2. Questions that deserve to be **upvoted** because they are great examples of exactly opposite of the downvote deserving ones. *There is no such thing as a good duplicate either*.
3. Questions that **you** can't qualify because you are not knowledgeable enough in the tag domains to make a judgement call because they are not obviously malformed and you lack the experience to judge if they are duplicates or useless in the tag domain. Just **do nothing** because you don't have a qualified opinion and move on.

### Voting for any other reason is mucking up the works.

A misplaced downvote (*in your opinion*) of `-2` is way less harmful ***to the system as a whole*** than a undeserved on **merit** upvote of `+5`. Answers are a different economy and a different metric.

### Voting up because of no explanatory comments is even worse!

#### The voting system is anonymous for a reason.

Generally anyone that is lazy writing a question that shows no research or is not useful is not going to look at it with a critical eye either to try and fix it. It would be too much effort and they have already displayed the level of effort they are willing to give.

#### The downvote description under the arrow is there for a reason.

These same people just whine about no comment on the downvote and they do not really care about the reason either because they never go back and edit the question if they do get a well thought out reason.

They general just say *"no, it's not"* and get in a pissing contest with whomever was stupid enough to post an explanatory comment. That person could have been reviewing other questions and downvoting them, but they are instead arguing with a help vampire with that time.

And they have publicly shamed the person that admits to the downvote, so others will gang up on that person in the future about the same thing and that person will just stop participating.

### My experience in the tags I am active in is that:

As a *general rule* every question that deserves a downvote also deserves a close vote that will add to the explanation even more. There might be some exceptions, but I can not think of any.

*The [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tags have the majority of the terrible questions by far, but not nearly as bad as the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) individually.*

Comment: There is such thing as a good duplicate. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290768/ | https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268665/ | https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307615

Comment: There is definitely a 4th category of question. Questions which are "meh". It is of course ridiculous to assert that all questions "deserve to be downvoted to oblivion" or "deserve to be upvoted because they are great examples " or are ones the reader is not qualified to judge.

Answer (score -4):

Yes and no.

Yes, it's wrong, because I feel you should vote based on the quality of the post alone, not on what other people think of it.

No, because you can still vote however you want for whatever reason. If everyone does it, it should balance out in the long run.

The good answers should rise to the top by means of mass voting.

This was relevant without taking reputation points into account. Your upvote will change the user's reputation positively even if the post ends up at 0. So you actually do change something.

I feel that the linear link between reputation points and votes makes voting different as your impact isn't just on the topic at hand. You influence user privileges at the same time. Maybe this was your intent (impact on user and not on question)?