# What should I do when I see a question being downvoted only for being "low level", but not bad?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, downvotes

Case in point, I recently answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35676291/for-loop-result-doesnt-make-sense-to-me). The question does show quite poor understanding of programming and/or the language in question, but we've all been there at some point. I don't think the question is badly asked -- it is clear, to the point, the asker shows some degree of exertion in trying to understand the question himself and is pointing out exactly where he's stuck, and the language/formatting is not bad.

Yet, the question is receiving downvotes. Although not in this particular case, I've often been across similar questions that also receive close votes (often for being "too broad", even though it clearly isn't). This behavior bugs me, and I'm not sure what to do about it. In this case, I even upvoted it to compensate, even though I know [I shouldn't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311406/is-using-an-up-vote-to-balance-out-a-down-vote-wrong). While not bad, it's not such a stellar question that I'd normally upvote it. At times, I've pointed out in the comments that I don't think the question deserves to be downvoted/closed, but that obviously doesn't help as the downvoters have already moved on and won't be looking at the question again.

I do realize there may be a point to be made that the question isn't particularly good, though, in that it's extremely specific to the asker's case and unlikely to be useful to anyone else. But you never know.

What should I do in cases like these? Am I in the wrong for not thinking questions of this kind should be downvoted? If I'm in the right, is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: If you call it out on meta like this you'll attract more votes to it. Some may be upvotes, others downvotes.

Comment: @RobertLongson: Would it really be good form to do a meta post every time I encountered specific questions like that? That would be a lot of seemingly pointless meta questions.

Comment: This isn't "low-level", it is no-level.  If you want help students to finish their homework then so be it.  Just don't assume you can count on anybody to still be there when *you* need help and it isn't low-level.  The advice this user needs is to stay at school, do his exercises, don't do drugs.

Comment: If you know the question doesn't deserve your upvote, and that upvoting despite that is poinsonous to the site, whyever do you highlight your intentional mis-behavior?

Comment: @Deduplicator: Just to indicate my frustration at the downvoting.

Comment: @Dolda2000 it seems to be attracting more downvotes now that you've called it out. That wasn't what you wanted was it?

Comment: "This behavior bugs me, and I'm not sure what to do about it" you do not know why the downvoters voted. If it bugs you that questions get down votes, go elsewhere. Down votes are part of the QA process of this site.

Comment: I find it depressing that someone could amass 13k reputation on this site without understanding how voting works.

Answer (score 5):

Why are you so bothered by people downvoting it?

Clearly they did not think that the question (A) was useful, (B) showed research effort, or (C) both. As such, it was fully reasonable and within their rights to downvote the question.

Yes, it would be inappropriate to close this question as being off topic (at least, given the currently provided closure reasons). It is certainly about programming, it is not too broad, it shows the code necessary to reproduce the problem and describes it adequately; in short, it is specific and answerable. If you see a question like this getting erroneously closed, then you should cast a vote to reopen it. If you think it's a particularly egregious abuse of closure powers and warrants *immediate* reopening, then flag it for moderator attention and explain your logic. Beware that the moderator may disagree with you, preferring as they do to let the community handle such matters on its own.

As to the point of upvoting to "counteract" downvotes, you've already admitted that it [is wrong and you shouldn't do it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311408), so please don't do it.

If you want to answer, and thereby encourage, questions like this, then there is no one that can stop you. Consider, though, that there is a difference between "beginner-level" questions and "no effort" questions. A few minutes thinking about the problem, aided by a debugger, sure seems like it would have been enough for the asker to solve this problem himself. As a bonus, by following these steps, he would learn even more than by being spoon-fed the information. As Hans adroitly warns in [his comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317830/what-should-i-do-when-i-see-a-question-being-downvoted-only-for-being-low-level#comment314537_317830), too much encouragement of questions like this runs the risk of driving away the experts that you want to have around to answer the difficult questions. It is important to strike the proper balance.

Allowing the questions while awarding them a low rank via voting is one way to achieve this balance. In fact, it is a completely valid use of the voting system. Questions with a low score will not be foist upon all visitors to the site, keeping them out of the face of experts, but still allowing them to be asked and answered by interested parties.

Comment: While it's true that I can't read the minds of the downvoters, it certainly seems to me that, rather than thinking that the question was "not useful", they think that the question was "not interesting" or "not useful to me". While I can see that being the case, it seems somewhat equivalent to me downvoting, for example, all Android questions just because I don't do Android programming and don't want them taking up space on the front page, perhaps driving off all the experts interested in subjects that I'm interested by. Is this analogy truly not correct to some extent?

Comment: I'm not really sure what is this distinction that you're trying to draw between "not useful" and "not useful to me." Of course my vote expresses my opinion. It cannot possibly express anyone else's. Yes, certainly there are people downvoting the question because it is "not interesting." Also because it showed no research effort. Asking poorly-researched, uninteresting questions is a good way to get downvotes. I'll ask again: what is wrong with that? Although such questions may be *acceptable*, they are not *good questions*, so they don't deserve upvotes. You are of course free to downvote...

Comment: ...Android questions if you like, but it kind of misses the point. I don't think people are showing up to this question and prejudging it based on the language/framework. I have no reason to believe that all of those votes didn't come from Java experts, who disliked the question for one or more of the reasons already discussed. And no, there are better ways to get ignore about topics you're uninterested in, like favorite tags and filters. Not true for lame, uninspired questions tagged with your favorite language. It is still unclear to me why you think this question *deserved a higher score*.