# How can I help questions in the NodeMCU tag avoid being downvoted or closed?

Tags: support, downvotes, vote-to-close

Many questions with the [nodemcu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nodemcu) tag get downvoted and/or flagged for closing. While it's true that some aren't on par quality-wise (many NodeMCU users seem to use SO for the first time) I don't understand the closing flags. Most of those claim the questions be off-topic.

Could it be that those voting to close those questions don't understand what NodeMCU/Lua is about? That they don't understand that it's a firmware you program with Lua? And that thus, those questions really *are* on-topic?

I suspect that even some of the downvotes can be attributed to the same cause. There are downvotes for questions that to me seem perfectly ok.

Or is there something *I myself* don't understand?

To improve the [nodemcu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nodemcu) tag info I submitted some changes for review (pending). I'd hate a low-quality tag info to be responsible for downvotes and flags.

Comment: First, understand that nothing can be "wrongly downvoted" other than in the case of serial voting, but that gets handled automagically by a system that runs daily.

Comment: I don't claim those downvotes be wrong - it's all subjective of course. However, I strive to better understand the possible reasons. I find it suspicious that it happens to so many questions with that tag.

Comment: my point is there's really nothing to address. People often vote for differing reasons. Maybe they don't understand the topic, maybe they think the question is unclear/poorly researched. there's really nothing that can be done about that. that's how votes work.

Comment: After looking at the first page of questions: I see non that are downvoted and look helpful for future visitors. Could you provide at least 2 or 3 links to questions where you think they are down and/or close-voted but are of good quality?

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Shouldn't "off topic" be only about...off topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192086)

Comment: SO suggested this related question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317830/what-should-i-do-when-i-see-a-question-being-downvoted-only-for-being-low-level. I now read the feedback there as well and I accept that my understanding of how things _should_ work is still somewhat different from super-users or moderators.

Comment: @KevinB: There's a difference between saying "we can't enforce 'correct' voting patterns, except for serial voting" (which is true) and saying "all votes are equally valid by definition unless serially cast and are utterly above reproach or question or social convention" (which is quite false). I'm really tired of seeing comments and answers that advance the latter view. Votes *should* be guided with detailed rules of thumb and helpful advice on what makes for a good vote. Some votes *are* terrible and wrong. Some voters *don't* have good judgement. "Nothing to address"? What nonsense!

Comment: As someone who works with embedded electronics I can't see too many "wrong" down votes - many seem too broad, lack research or are really hardware questions. It's probably pretty common with anything that targets novices - sometimes it's hard to identify the difference between firmware and hardware problems especially if you don't have the correct test gear and experience.

Comment: @NathanTuggy votes need to be *presumed* valid, because you can't do otherwise without either reading minds, or asking voters to deanonymize themselves, which is a cardinal sin. You can provide all the guidance you want, but ideally every time someone posts "why the downvotes?", a small gnome would exit the side of their monitor and hit them with a mallet.

Comment: @hobbs: Well, sure, I *said* you can't invalidate votes. But double-thinking your way to "there is nothing wrong with this sympathy vote on a terrible question. We have always been at war with node.jsia."? I draw the line at that, fairly sharply. In other words, we should always keep in mind that a vote can be lousy without being invalid, and reserve the right to criticize and guide without trying to "fix" votes unilaterally. Never let the fact that a vote cannot be invalidated make you pretend it's a good vote when it isn't.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, you might want to [edit the tag wiki excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/nodemcu/info):

> An open-source firmware and development kit that helps you to prototype your IOT product within a few Lua script lines. http://nodemcu.com/index_en.html

There's no point to putting a URL in the excerpt, but apart from that it doesn't do much to explain what questions in the tag should be *about*:

- Firmware dev?
- APIs?
- Lua on NodeMCU?
- All of the above?
- None of the above?

That's not going to immediately solve your problem, but it'll offer a bit of immediate guidance to both askers *and voters* as to what they should be looking for.

Then... **Edit.**

Yes, a lot of lackluster questions are being asked. Folks ask questions that are vague, contain multiple distinct questions, lack detail... You, knowing something about the topic, are well-equipped to both guide them *and* ensure they look good in front of voters who might be less familiar with the topic:

- Correct grammar & spelling
- Ensure there's a descriptive title
- Strip out all but the most essential question (and leave a comment advising the asker that they can ask additional questions once their first is answered)
- Add contextual details to help others find the question in the future (this is just to save you time down the road, but also helps make the question look more useful).

The nice thing about smaller tags like this is that you *can* actually make a substantive difference using only the Edit privilege - so don't hesitate to do so! In particular, don't neglect to do this if you're *answering* a question - [there are even badges for this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/10/07/new-editing-badges-and-enhancements-to-suggested-edits/)!

Finally, be aware that when there are close votes pending on questions in a particular tag, you can review *only* those questions by filtering review: [this link will let you review all questions pending closure in the nodemcu tag](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=nodemcu). This can be a great way to find questions that could use a bit of assistance.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I never looked at it that way. And thanks for the helpful edit at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/356904/4