# Is it fine to vote up/down to compensate the votes of others?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting, upvotes

Sometimes I see a question/answer in SO that has so many down-votes but I think it's not such a bad question but also not a good question that would deserve a vote-up. In such cases I don't know if it's fine to vote-up the question just because I think that question does not deserve the votes it has? or in general case is it fine to vote from the below formula:

```
my vote = sign(the vote count I believe the question deserves to have - the votes it actually has)
```

**Edited after reading the comments and thinking a little bit more about it:**

## why I think it can be good.

The thing is that I think it happens so often in SE that one sees a post and finds it useless (especially about questions) and they immediately down-vote it and just forget about the question and let go of it. But for example the OP comes back tomorrow (for example in a scenario where the OP has asked a question at night and slept to wake up to a good answer the next day) and sees that they have gotten many down-votes and they read the comments and just realize they had asked their question in a bad way. So they edit their question to make it better and it really becomes a good question but the down-voters will never come back to find the edited question useful and take back their down-votes. Also somehow the same thing happens when an old question has some answers with high votes but they are obsolete.

## why I think my way of voting is a solution to these problems.

Because if everyone is voting the way I do. the votes will lead to a result that is close to the sum of the opinions of everyone. But the people who voted later will have a little more effect than the people who had voted long time ago.(It's something statistical and I think there is mathematical formulation that my idea is rigth:D)

Comment: No, [don't vote to try to change the score](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311408/603977). Vote because you think the post is good or bad.

Comment: Well, I would not upvote a bad question or downvote a good one, just because of the votes it already has.  If I think it's a bad question, I don't mind making -100 into -101.  That's just me, though.  Your vote is your own - use it how youi wish.  That's why it's called a 'vote' :)

Comment: Of course it is, you can vote for whatever reason you want. I just find that reasoning rather poor and not helpful.

Comment: @KevinB oh, I agree.  Others seem to differ:(

Comment: Your example of why you think it can be good is different than what you ask in the title though. In your example you say it yourself "they edit the question to be a good question". That means that upvoting is CORRECT. this isn't "hey the score is at -5, I think it should be -3, so I'm upvoting".  One is voting on the merit of the post. The other isn't

Comment: @Patrice They key point being that if you would have upvoted the question, after the edit, *even if it had never been downvoted*, then you now think that the post is useful, and you should indeed upvote it.  Likewise for the second example, if you would downvote the answer because you feel that the obsolete answer isn't helpful, and would have done so *even if the post hadn't attracted upvotes*, then you are indeed voting based on your opinion of the usefulness of the post, and the vote is appropriate.

Comment: I don't think this post deserves this many down-votes... here, take an up-vote

Comment: @Patrice I edited the question for you.

Comment: @Servy please see my edit.

Comment: Don't completely change the question after you get an answer. Note that if the OP has edited and the question is now useful, you are *not* voting because you think it deserves a higher score, you are voting *because it's useful*

Comment: @yukashimahuksay So in your example you show a question that 5 out of the 7 people that see it think is a bad question that isn't useful, and that only one out of the seven people that see it think is useful (and one with no opinion on the quality of the question), and in your view you think it's *better* when that question has a final score of +1, then when it has a final score of -3.  In other words you think that the one person who thinks that the question is good should outweigh the opinions of the 6 people who *don't* think it's useful.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my example.

Comment: I'm gonna ask a new question because jon thinks I've completely changed the question.

Comment: @yukashimahuksay How did I misunderstand your example?

Comment: I find one weird thing in your new example.... You can't really use the "here is what they would believe BEFORE, and AFTER edit", then pull your numbers with votes having the edit in the middle of the voting. You use the score a & b think the question should be after the edit to prove that the +1 is ok. But a and b don't RE vote for this.... the community shouldn't strive to guess what a and b believe the score post-edit should be and vote based on THAT...

Comment: Voting to compensate other votes is to Stack Overflow what premature optimisation is to software development.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I don't see how

Comment: @yukashimahuksay How are they not? Premature optimization is useless. It wastes time. It distracts from the real task. "Compensating" votes are useless. They waste other people's time, giving a wrong signal about a post. They distract from the real task.

Comment: ... more seriously, I now remember I was thinking about the saying "premature optimization is the root of all evil". Compensating votes are trash (respectfully. the votes are trash, not necessarily the person casting them).

Answer (score 26):

The upvote tooltip is, "This question/answer is useful" not "this question/answer has a lower score than I think it should have".  Likewise, the downvote tooltip is "this question/answer is not useful", not "this question/answer has a higher score than I think it should have".

If you think a post is useful, upvote it.  If you think a post isn't useful, downvote it.  Let other people express their own opinions in their own votes.

While it's not particularly *enforceable*, it is technically violating the sites rules to cast a vote that contradicts whether or not you think the post is useful.  (Users are of course given very wide latitude as to what criteria they use to judge the usefulness of a post, but you *are* expected to vote based on how useful you think the post is.)

Comment: Unless you go totally Meta and reason "the *upvoting* on this terrible question is not useful".

Comment: @usr2564301 If the question is terrible, then it merits downvotes.  That's true whether or not other people have upvoted it.

Comment: Good point. Then we need a Schroedinger voting system, where you cannot vote after you have seen the current plus/minus distribution.