# Why were my votes reset?

Tags: support, bug, voting

This morning, I got the Civic Duty badge on Stack Overflow (for 300 votes cast total) but when I looked at my votes just now, I only have my 2 most recent votes.

Is this a bug or were they reset for a specific reason? If so, why?

As a side note relating my votes, I have not been given the "Critic" badge despite casting a downvote

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you checked the profile you got the badge on? ([meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/current) vs [main](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current))

Comment: @Cerbrus Thanks and yes, I got the badge on the main Stack Overflow but I now only have 2 votes there.

Comment: You should have a mod message. If not, I am happy to discuss the flag I raised and the response I got, but I am intentionally not discussing it immediately incase you don't want anything stated publically.

Comment: @ThomA I have not received a message, could you please tell me more? (I don't mind if it's public, thanks).

Comment: Your votes were invalidated less than 2 hours prior to this question being posted. I was not the moderator who handled this issue. I've pinged that moderator informing them about this MSO question. They would have also been pinged when the Community Manager responded to them after the CM performed the vote invalidations. Given the asynchronous nature of the communications and that moderators are volunteers without set hours, it's not surprising that there's a notable delay between when the invalidations were performed and any communication from the handling moderator to the user.

Comment: *"I have not been given the "Critic" badge despite casting a downvote"* Some badges aren't awarded immediately; there is an scheduled processes that award some. Critic could well be one of those, considering it hasn't been awarded in [14 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/7/critic).

Comment: And, as of 33 minutes ago, you have now been awarded it.

Comment: Announcer is a weird one. I won't get a new announcer badge for a couple years, then I'll get 2-3 at effectively the same time.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

<sub>This answer is based off the information I have access to, it does not include results of any further moderator actions nor do I have knowledge of any moderator messages that were sent to you.</sub>

Personally, I raised a flag against one of your posts a few days ago as your voting looked suspicious. I had noticed that as a user of (then) 8 days you had achieved the [Vox Populi](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1108/vox-populi?userid=22704161) badge on the day you signed up; a badge that means you used your maximum votes of 40 in a single day. I also noticed that on that day you had made a significant number (I think it was 44). This had a significant smell to it. When I raised the flag, you were at almost 300 votes (meaning you had likely voted ~40 times *every* day).

Many new users are completely unfamiliar with the voting system, you had used *all* of your on the first day; this seemed like the votes weren't legitimate. Such a large volume, on such a small amount of days, made it appear that the votes weren't because you found the content useful but for something else (perhaps a voting ring). As a result I stated in the flag that the votes did not seem to be genuine and that something seemed awry.

The response I got to the flag, today, was:

> looks like they were attempting to get the Civic Duty badge, we'll look into it

I had, in truth, only noticed that this flag had been marked as useful about 10 minutes before your post and too noticed that your votes had been deleted. This is, presumably, a result of the findings of the moderator team.

If the moderator's assumption is correct, and you were just aiming for the [Civic Duty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty?userid=22704161) badge, well you have achieved it, however, this could (apparently has) been seen as an abuse of the voting system. Votes should be used to denote content personally you found (not) helpful/useful. Just voting on content you find to get a badge, and ensuring you use the maximum number of votes on several days, is not going to help demonstrate your true feelings on the content.

Of course, if this isn't correct, and you truly had found *around* **300** posts helpful in the last ~9 days, then your votes were warranted, but (with the greatest respects) I find this unlikely.

Comment: The fact that this meta posts references not one but two badges kind of gives away where the focus is too.

Comment: @ThomA Thanks for your response. I'm not sure what you mean by a 'voting ring' so I don't think that's what I was doing. I was just trying to help people by upvoting them (Because I'd gotten a lot of heavily downvoted posts and it sucks). Should I not vote so much? What exactly are the rules on when and where I should vote, I kind of assumed I was free to vote as I please?

Comment: You are free to use your votes as you see fit, to a *degree*, @ryley . It is expected that you should be voting because the content you found was (not) helpful/useful, as I stated. As I mentioned, I find it unlikely that in the course of 8 days you really did find over *200* posts that were helpful/useful to ***you***. That's a significant amount of content.

Comment: @ryley That is not how voting works, and is another form of abuse. Targeted voting is not correct usage. Voting is a content ranking mechanism, not a nicety initiative.

Comment: @ryley "_I was just trying to help people by upvoting them_" voting is not meant for people, it is for **posts**. Anyway how is upvoting someones post helping them? Reputation is just some internet points.

Comment: @AndreasismovingtoCodidact Yes I understand that. I wasn't upvoting just to be nice. I was just trying to be liberal with my upvotes, what is wrong with that?

Comment: @ryley: "Yes I understand that" and "I was just trying to be liberal with my upvotes" are contradictory, or nearly so. You say you understand, yet it seems you do not understand.

Comment: @ryley A voting ring is when a group of accounts are repeatedly casting upvotes on each other to artificially increase their reputation or get badges (or downvotes to target a user). Votes should be cast based on the _content_ of a post, not based on the _user_ that posted it. **Voting rings are prohibited** and users can (and do) receive suspensions for having them. The problem is that **you shouldn't be casting votes to be nice (or to be hurtful), but rather based on the quality of content**.

Comment: *"Because I'd gotten a lot of heavily downvoted posts and it sucks"* wait a minute... That doesn't make sense, @ryley . You made 40 votes on your *very first* day of being a member and had 2 posts which aren't downvoted. Where had you got heavily downvoted? Have you created a new account? I hope it wasn't to get around a question ban on your other account...

Comment: @ThomA I have not ban evaded, I have had several questions and answers on this account that were downvoted and closed  (which I have since deleted)

Comment: @Gimby I mentioned it because it was another voting-related issue I had and I thought they might be related. Why is your first thought that I am trying to hoard as many badges as I can?

Comment: @ryley Voting is how people who are unfamiliar (but want to gain familiarity) tell whether or not a post is good content that they should learn from. If you drop mercy votes you aren't helping, you're hindering future learners by directing them to potentially bad information. Do enough of that and Stack Overflow becomes useless.

Comment: Side note: Deleted content is still used by the server to determine when you can next ask or answer a question. Rack up enough low-score deleted questions and you'll find your ability to ask more questions is severely rate-limited even though you may still have a respectable amount of reputation. With Answers there doesn't seem to be a rate limit. You're pretty much cut off until some of the low-scored answers are upvoted by future visitors. If the answers are deleted and you don't have non-deleted questions that can be upvoted, regaining answering privileges will never happen.

Comment: Okay, let's stop the public speculation about ban evasion.  If you think someone's evading a ban, put the evidence in a flag.

Comment: @ryley It wasn't my first thought.

Comment: @ryley, not to pile on but you might want to read [Is it wrong to use an upvote to balance out a downvote?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311406/354577)