# Is it OK to ask same question if it is outdated for better/newer answer/solution?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, accepted-answer

If there exists a question in Stack Overflow that is an accepted answer but the date of it was for so long ago that there is great chance new/better answers might come along. Users don't pay attention to old questions that are already answered without asking it again to be more recently.

For example, Switch statement in Java wasn't available in JDK prior JDK 7 but now it is possible.

Is it OK to ask it again to get update (answer) even though not sure if there is one?

Comment: if you know an updated answer exists why not add an answer there instead of asking again?

Comment: Or better yet, follow the help center: Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it. Common reasons for edits include: [...] To correct minor mistakes or **add updates as the post ages**.

Comment: See also [Promoting new answers to old questions - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267018/promoting-new-answers-to-old-questions)  ;;; [What to do when the question you want to ask is a duplicate? - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253924/what-to-do-when-the-question-you-want-to-ask-is-a-duplicate)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it OK to ask it again to get update (answer) even though not sure if there is one?

No. If you're not sure there is an updated answer, that would imply that you haven't tried the existing answers to see if an updated answer is even needed. Don't add duplicate questions based on the speculation that there might be newer answers. If there are new answers people can add them to the old question.

(Also, the switch statement was available long before Java 7. They just added the ability to switch on `String` values in that release.)

Comment: :D I meant switch statement for `String` type as you mentioned.

Comment: Unfortunately this method does not work if the accepted answer say "there's no existing solution because ABC" ____________________________________________________________________________________________ Note: while it's not allowed to post a new question, adding a bounty to the old question is allowed (but quite expensive)