# What to do if I find a question for my problem, but I have different thing to say? Why is editing the old question bad?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, duplicate-questions, community-wiki

The questions [What should I do if there is a question already made for my problem but has never been answered? (duplicate)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416422/3416774) and [What can you do when the question you want to ask is a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253924/3416774) don't seem to say anything about having different thing to say.

For example, I have the problem of [React: Detect click outside multiple components](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58626061/3416774) and the question is what I'm looking for. It has 4 upvotes and a diagram. Nice. The answer doesn't satisfy me, as it doesn't have the code.

I also try using ref hook, and have code for that. I think add that to the original question will be better for everyone. From my impression of the above meta questions, asking a new question is the way to go, but they don't explicitly explain why adding to the old question is bad. Or why we shouldn't make the old one a wiki one. The question has 4 votes, why don't we accumulate the number to it? It has a mediocre answer, why don't we let it have more exposure? Not to mention the SEO score (I don't know the exact term) it has already built. Sure we can mark it as duplicate to the newer question, but why make the users have to click to another link?

Comment: About the question you want to ask, have you considered using the [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) or [focusout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusout_event) events?

Comment: Changing the question would invalidate any existing answers. If you have a new question just ask it and explain why the current Q&A is not sufficient.

Comment: @Paulie_D why existing answers will be invalidate if the question is still the same?

Comment: It won't be the same if you edit it, will it?

Comment: If the question is the same and you aren't satisfied with the answer for some reason consider adding a bounty to it.

Comment: @Paulie_D well, if I feel that my edit would make the question different, even slightly, then I wouldn't have to ask this meta question. I have a strong feeling that it wouldn't change (in intend, not content)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat done

Comment: "The answer doesn't satisfy me, as it doesn't have the code." **If it had code, would it satisfy you?** If yes: editing the question doesn't help to get an answer with code, and changing the question is **expected not to invalidate** existing answers (this is covered by **many** previous Meta Q&As and probably in the Help Center as well). If no: then you probably have a new question, and you **need to explain why** you can't just take possible code for that answer and solve the problem.

Comment: "I also try using ref hook, and have code for that." - if you mean that you wrote code that uses "ref hook" (whatever that means), and *that code solves the problem*, **then you are answering** the question, not asking it.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I mean my code doesn't work. I know changing the question is expected not to invalidate existing answers; what I argue here is that adding my part won't invalidate any existing answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the question is what I'm looking for. It has 4 upvotes and a diagram. Nice. The answer doesn't satisfy me, as it doesn't have the code.

Great, there is a tried and true way to proceed here: post a bounty with a description of seeking an updated or better answer *with code*. The bigger your bounty, the more likely you are to get better answers. I'd recommend a 200+ reputation bounty, personally, to maximize your chances of getting a good response set.

> I also try using ref hook, and have code for that. I think add that to the original question will be better for everyone.

No, that's not the case. Adding code that OP didn't use is changing the question they asked and risks invalidating the existing answers.

> From my impression of the above meta questions, asking a new question is the way to go, but they don't explicitly explain why adding to the old question is bad

Because even if the existing answers still would technically work with your code, if your code utilizes something OP's didn't, and that different code enables a novel solution, all the existing answers will suddenly appear worse for apparently ignoring that aspect. People might comment asking "why didn't you just do X that works perfectly with react hooks?" and they'll have to explain "well that wasn't in the question when I answered it".